# Accessing Certain Column in a Range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to access column 2 in a specific range, and then counting the cells with constants in them.  Right now what I have is accessing the range, but not a specific column in the range, but rather the entire range... thus counting too many constants.

```
X = Range("MAIN_LIST").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Is there a way for me to access a specific column in this range?  I tried to do this somehow with:

```
X = Range("MAIN_LIST").Column(2).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

but am getting a syntax error.  Anyone know the specific syntax to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not positive, but is the syntax error that you wrote `Column` and not `Columns`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just:

```
Range("MAIN_LIST").Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

The method is `Columns`, not `Column`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837125(v=office.14).aspx

Also, while it's not an error:  Using the method `Cells` is redundant/unnecessary, the `Range` object itself already is comprised of its `Cells`, and likewise any particular column in that range is also comprised of *its* `Cells` :)

Comment: Thanks David.  Quick question:  should it be Columns(,2) since it is telling me that format of Columns is Column(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)?

Comment: I think the intellisense is wrong in that. You definitely can't pass it two arguments that will raise an error.